# Heroku Node.js - Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT

Tags: html, css, node.js, heroku

When I am deploying my website on Heroku it says:-

Application error

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
Heroku logs --tail

And in the logs, when I check, there seems nothing major. It's given:-

```
2020-09-20T23:56:47.790226+00:00 app[web.1]: 

2020-09-20T23:56:48.040459+00:00 app[web.1]: SERVER IS RUNNIG AT PORT 8000

2020-09-20T23:56:48.040768+00:00 app[web.1]: Server runnung at http://127.0.0.1:5500

2020-09-20T23:57:44.991177+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

2020-09-20T23:57:45.017244+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL

2020-09-20T23:57:45.087257+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137

2020-09-20T23:57:45.132990+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2020-09-21T02:05:44.125661+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sheetsw.herokuapp.com request_id=b87a2aae-a1d1-44d4-9f4e-2d10421edec6 fwd="27.60.151.127" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2020-09-21T02:05:46.906817+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sheetsw.herokuapp.com request_id=a46e447c-e111-4954-a6c6-a1e928013a82 fwd="27.60.151.127" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2020-09-21T02:06:05.637299+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=sheetsw.herokuapp.com request_id=d6aa7d9b-60eb-450c-8ceb-c063faad3917 fwd="27.60.151.127" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Can you please tell me where I am wrong and why, and also please how can I overcome this problem?

My server.js file:-

```
    const express = require("express");

const fs = require('fs');

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const  bodyParser = require('body-parser');
/** 
const port= 80; 
**/

const hostname= '127.0.0.1';
const port= 5500;

const path = require('path');


const app = express();

app.get('/register.html',(req,res) => {

 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/register.html')
})

/**app.use(express.static('./')); 
**/
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
sending();


function sending(){

   

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service:'gmail',
    auth:{
        user:'collectnis@gmail.com',
        pass:'free_fire123'        
    }
});

function sendEmail(mail)
{
 var mailOptions= {
     from: 'collectnis@gmail.com',
     to:mail.to,
     subject: mail.subject,
     html: mail.body
 }

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err+"                    "+mail.to)
    }
    else {
        console.log("Email sent: "+info.response)
    }
})
}

app.post('/register.html', (req,res)=> {
    mail= {
        to:req.body.to_address,
        subject:"Sheets_Wrap - project details",
        body:req.body.NAME + "    ------------/////////////------------     "+ req.body.phone + "    ------------/////////////------------     " + req.body.email_body + "    ------------/////////////------------     " + req.body.code
    }
    sendEmail(mail)
    res.redirect('/register.html')
})


app.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log('SERVER IS RUNNIG AT PORT 8000')
    console.log(`Server runnung at http://localhost:${port}/register.html`);
})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue: Your Node.js app is improperly configured to bind to a port other than the one provided by Heroku via the $PORT environment variable.

Heroku dynos expose a dynamic port for your app to bind to. This value is exposed in the $PORT env var. You must change your code to bind to this port instead. For example:

```
//Replace your hardcoded port to process.env.PORT
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Our app is running on port ${ PORT }`);
});
```

This will use the $PORT env var if available, or fall back to a default port (useful for local development). Note that when browsing to your application on Heroku, you still use port 80 ([your-application].herokuapp.com) and not the port that your process binds on.